# nginx (openresty) get current peer

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, openresty

there is an openresty load balancer in front of several instances of container app, the load balancer will use round robbin to route traffic to each app instance.
Is there a way I can record the paired backend server IP address into redis? the upstream is fixed, it is dynamic.

I tried to use upstream but it seems only work with fixed upstream {}, not dynamic one

```
docker-compose up --scale nginx_html_app=2
```

```
-- this is docker-compose.yml
nginx_html_app:
    build: nginx_html_app
proxy:
    build: proxy
    ports:
        - "9000:80"

-- this is proxy.conf
server{
    listen 80;
    set $upstream http://nginx_html_app
    location / {
        some_lua_block{
            # get paired backend IP, eg: 172.18.0.3 (nginx_html_app 1)
            # save to redis (know how to do this)
        }
        proxy_pass $upstream
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upstream IP and port are available in `ngx.var.upstream_addr` variable, in `header_filter_by_lua` and `log_by_lua`. But logging in the first place will make requests wait on your writes to complete, and in the second one network sockets aren't available, so you need to queue your logging and fire it in a timer.

Something like that (untested but should help you to get the idea):

app.lua - separate file, we need it so that global state will be cached:

```
M = {}

local queue = {}

function M.init()
  ngx.timer.every(1.0, function(premature)
    if premature then return end
    -- push queue to redis and clear it
  end)
end

function M.log()
  queue[#queue+1] = ngx.var.upstream_addr
end

return M
```

nginx:

```
init_worker_by_lua_block { require('app.lua').init() }


log_by_lua_block { -- or header_filter_by_lua_block
  require('app.lua').log()
}
```

Comment: ngx.var.upstream_addr is null or empty based on my test. I tried it in access_lua_block.
Haven't tried log_by_lua_block thought. But a good one!

Comment: It will be available only _after_ nginx communicates with upstream, take a look at request phase order: https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#directives